# flutter remove animation of pushName router

Tags: flutter, dart, animation, navigation, router

I've use `pushNamed` for my routers.
I want to remove animation of push pages in `pushNamed` .
can anyone help me please how can I do that?
for example remove animation for push '/' :

```
Navigator.pushNamed(
    context,
    '/',
    arguments: {
       "title": "explore",
         },);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to control the transition of your route navigation, you have to use the `Navigator.of(context).push()` function with your custom `PageRouteBuilder`. The `PageRouteBuilder`'s `pageBuilder` returns your target page's widget and you can pass arguments as widget parameters this way.

Try this:

```dart
Navigator.of(context).push(
          PageRouteBuilder(
            pageBuilder: (BuildContext context, _, __) {
              return YourTargetPageWidget(/* Pass your arguments as widget params*/);
            },
          ),
        )
```